# Run ARCore application on Android emulator

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I have created an android build(.apk) for HelloAR example in unity after following the steps written [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart).

And also created an android emulator to test the Android build by following the steps given [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator).

But I am not able to install ARCore on the emulator.

After installing the Android build of HelloAR application on the emulator (without installing ARCore) the application ended with a white screen.

Is there anything else I have to do to run the application on emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to test and debug your app without deploying to the actual phone, You can use [Eazy ARCore Interface](https://github.com/VR-House/Eazy-ARCore-Interface). This is a little tool I wrote so I can develop and debug my ARCore projects from within the editor.

It makes things easier when it comes to writing your game logic. ARcore is simulated for you in the editor.

When you are finished and want to deploy to device, no changes are required. Just build and deploy.

Comment: Thanks, JackMini36. Actually, I don't have supported device currently. So I will try Eazy ARCore Interface.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment ARCore projects created in Unity can not be started in an emulator. See [here.](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/108)

But it is possible to use Android Studio and Android NDK to make it run in the Emulator. See [here.](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/quickstart)

Maybe they will integrate support for the emulator in unity in the future.

Comment: Thank you, Agyss for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

> If your smartphone doesn't support ARCore or you have no phone but need to debug an AR app – Android emulator is a great way to do it.

**Follow these steps to install Android Virtual Device (AVD)**:

- Make sure Android Debug Bridge (`adb`) is installed and works properly.
- Download the latest [ARCore_emulator.apk](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) from ***GitHub***.
- Choose AVD using menu **`Tools`** > **`AVD Manager`** and run it.
- Type this command in Terminal ***while the virtual device is running***:

  ```
  adb install -r ARCore_1.8.0.x86_for_emulator.apk
  ```
- Repeat previous steps for additional AVDs you’d like to use on port 5554.

Hope this helps.